# Using mat-error in nested reactive form group

Tags: angular

I have a nested `FormGroup`

```
this.outerForm= this.formBuilder.group({
  firstFormGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
    nserNumber: ['', Validators.required]
  }),
  ...
});
```

I'm trying the following:

```
<fieldset formGroupName="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter NSER</ng-template>
        <div class="formRow">
          <div class="col-custom-col-50">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="NSER number" id='nserNumber' formControlName="nserNumber">
              <mat-error *ngIf="outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.controls.nserNumber.required">Required</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <pre>{{outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.controls.nserNumber | json}}</pre> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

But this mat-error is not working. Please help

Comment: can you try `hasError` like `outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.controls.nserNumber.hasError('required')"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead to do

```
<mat-error *ngIf="outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.controls.nserNumber.required">
```

do this:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.get('nserNumber').hasError('required') && (outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.get('nserNumber').dirty || outerForm.controls.firstFormGroup.get('nserNumber').touched)">
```

Answer (score 2):

In your **component.ts**, you should create a `getter` method to get the controls of your `firstFormGroup`.

```
get firstFormGroupControls() {
  return this.outerForm.get('firstFormGroup')['controls'];
}
```

In your **component.html**, you can access the `firstFormGroupControls` like below:

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="firstFormGroupControls.nserNumber.required">Required</mat-error>
```

Comment: You have to define different getters for different form groups.

Comment: I have done thta, but, mat-error is not showing, infact the interpolation {{firstFormGroupControls.nserNumber.required}} is showing nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can access the desired nested FormControl directly using dot expression like this

```
<mat-error *ngIf="outerForm.get('firstFormGroup.nserNumber').errors.required">
<!-- or -->
<mat-error *ngIf="outerForm.get('firstFormGroup.nserNumber').hasError('required')">
```

The accepted answer also contains dirty/touched checks which are unnecessary when using mat-error component, Material library handles this by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did this:

in the component file:

```
this.address = this.formBuilder.group({
  main: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  state: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  postal: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
})

ngOnInit(): void {
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  fullName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  telephone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  address: this.address
})
```

}

in the HTML:

```
<form
        [formGroup]="profileForm"
        (ngSubmit)="updateProfile()"
>
<form formGroupName="address">
                    <mat-form-field
                        appearance="outline"
                        class="example-full-width"
                    >
                        <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
                        <textarea
                            rows="15"
                            matInput
                            formControlName="main"
                        ></textarea>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="address.controls['main'].hasError('required')">Address is required</mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <table class="example-full-width">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <mat-form-field
                                        appearance="outline"
                                        class="example-full-width"
                                    >
                                        <mat-label>City</mat-label>
                                        <input
                                            matInput
                                            placeholder="Ex. Bangalore"
                                            formControlName="city"
                                        >
                                        <mat-error *ngIf="address.controls['city'].hasError('required')">City is required</mat-error>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <mat-form-field
                                        appearance="outline"
                                        class="example-full-width"
                                    >
                                        <mat-label>State</mat-label>
                                        <input
                                            matInput
                                            placeholder="Ex. Karnataka"
                                            formControlName="state"
                                        >
                                        <mat-error *ngIf="address.controls['state'].hasError('required')">State is required</mat-error>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <mat-form-field
                                        appearance="outline"
                                        class="example-full-width"
                                    >
                                        <mat-label>Postal Code</mat-label>
                                        <input
                                            matInput
                                            #postalCode
                                            maxlength="5"
                                            placeholder="Ex. 94105"
                                            value
                                            maxlength="6"
                                            minlength="6"
                                            formControlName="postal"
                                        >
                                        <mat-error *ngIf="address.controls['postal'].hasError('required')">Postal Code is required</mat-error>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
</form>
```

Working fine for me, here is a screenshot:

[image]